# django: set model fields as choices in models.py

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-models

Is it possible to set the choices of a field from another table?
for example

```
class Initial_Exam(models.Model):
    Question_category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices = Job.Job_Position)

class Job(models.Model):
    Job_Position = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
```

something like that

Comment: Isn't that what a ForeignKey is for?

Comment: Yes that makes sense but how would i display the Job_Position as choices in the admin, instead of just numbers, can i have link if there is any?

Comment: You are over twisting your implementation. You should have a foreign key to `Job` and write `__unicode__` function for the `Job` model to return the `Job_Postion`. Or if the `Job_Position` is a limited set of strings then define the choices inside the `Initial_Exam` itself. God, PEP is dead!

Comment: Thanks i get it know. I'.m really confused with python, it's not the same as any other language i tried

Comment: I can't see anything specific to Python here, so not sure what's confusing you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close this:
As commented above, instead of twisting my implementation, setting the foreign key for `Initial_Exam` and using `__unicode__` on `Job` did the job

should look like this:

`class Job(models.Model):
    Job_Position = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Job_Requirements`

that would display the `Job_Position` as choices in the admin panel

I thank the community, really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely tie to another model with a ForeignKey relationship, but if you've got a smaller number of choices, here's a pattern you might want to consider for smaller choice lists (I use it for fairly constant choice lists less than 10):

```
class FrequencyType(models.Model):

    FREQ_MONTHLY = 1
    FREQ_QUARTERLY = 3
    FREQ_YEARLY = 12

    FREQ_CHOICES = (
        (FREQ_MONTHLY, 'Monthly'),
        (FREQ_QUARTERLY, 'Quarterly'),
        (FREQ_YEARLY, 'Yearly'),
    )

    frequency = models.SmallIntegerField(default=FREQ_MONTHLY, choices=FREQ_CHOICES)
```

or, another example:

```
class YesNoModel(models.Model):
    NO = 0
    YES = 1

    YESNO_CHOICES = (
        (NO, 'No'),
        (YES, 'Yes'),
    )

    weight = models.IntegerField(default=NO, choices=YESNO_CHOICES)
```

Good luck.